# Non-ASCII chars in python file deletes other chars

Tags: python, bash, unicode, ssh, character-encoding

I really wasn't sure what to name this question. Let me just explain what happens. I wanted to type something like `test ('ö')` in a python file using nano.

```
test ('ö    #so far so good, but when I type the closing citation mark: 
test 'ö'    #that's happening
```

This is just one of several strange things that occurs when typing non-ASCII characters in python files in the terminal.

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 12.04 through SSH on a Mac OS X 10.8
- Python 2.7.3
- Bash
- LANG and LANGUAGE both set to sv_SE

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the terminal.

Comment: This is **not** a Python problem; Python doesn't handle input methods, your terminal does. And *definitely* not when you are using Nano, no Python code is involved when using that editor.

Comment: The exact same process works as expected with test.txt.

Comment: Ok, it kind of works as expected. It's not misbehaving in the same way. But I'm afraid I'm still clueless as to what to do.

Comment: Ok, that helped after all. Turns out the locale had to be set to `sv_SE.utf8` rather than `sv_SE` or `sv_SE.UTF-8`.

Comment: Post your comment as an answer so people that have this same problem will more easily see it.

Comment: If you want to use `Terminal.app` for non-UTF-8 sessions (like connecting to a linux box that doesn't have an appropriate locale), you can open Preferences, go to Settings, create a new Profile, select it, click Advanced, and change the Character Encoding to, e.g., "Western (ISO Latin 1)". (If you're using `iTerm`/`iTerm2` instead of `Terminal`, it's under Profiles, Terminal instead of Settings, Advanced.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the locale had to be set to sv_SE.utf8 rather than sv_SE or sv_SE.UTF-8. If you're from another country than Sweden (which statistically seems reasonable to assume) you obviously have to find the right locale name for your language and location.

Then just do this to generate (optional) your locale, and set it:

```
locale-gen sv_SE.utf8
locale-update LANG=sv_SE.utf8
reboot
```

Replace LANG for any other environment variables you need to set. This will create/modify the file /etc/default/locale.